# Redshift Serverless Error: incompatible Parquet schema for default integer during COPY

Tags: pandas, amazon-redshift, amazon-redshift-serverless

I'm using a Python script to read a CSV file using Pandas, add some metadata columns to it, generate a parquet file and finally COPY it into Redshift Serverless. However, Redshift Serverless complains that one of the metadata columns has an incompatible data type.

This is how the whole script goes:

```
df = pd.read_csv(...)
df['processing_attempts'] = pd.Series(0, index=df.index) # I need an integer initialized to zero
# convert using Pyarrow
table = pa.Table.from_pandas(df)
pq.write_table(table, f'{file_name}.parquet')
```

When I do a `df.info()`, I can see that the column has a type of `int64`, which, based on my StackOverflow readings so far, is what it should be.

In the destination table, the column type is `INT`, so I'm surprised I'm getting this incompatibility error. Any ideas as to what might be off here?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out myself. The `INT` type in Redshift is 4-byte long, so I needed to set my dtype to `Int32` and not `Int64`. Hope this helps someone!